# Can't access CentOS samba file server using IP address but can using domain name in Windows Explorer

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, samba, active-directory

I have set up a samba file server on CentOS that is on a domain. AD users can access it through Windows Explorer using its domain name, but they cannot access it through using its IP address. When users attempt to use the IP address they get a message stating the domain is not available. What would be the solution for this?

Edit: Below is output of ip addr

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:8b:f1:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.192.52/24 brd 192.168.192.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6002:6cea:3dad:bc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:24:6b:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:24:6b:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Is the IP address really the right one? What do the Samba log files tell you (you might need to increase the log level in `smb.conf` to 3 or even 4)

Comment: Yes the IP address is correct. I can ssh into it from that IP address with no problems.

Comment: What about the log files?

Comment: Are there multiple IP addresses on the samba server? Can "you" connect to it via its IP address? Add the output of `ip addr` on the CentOS machine to your question.

Comment: Nasir, there is only one ip address on the server. I can ssh into it from another linux machine and putty on a windows machne via its IP, but I cannot access it on Windows File Explorer via its IP.

Comment: roaima, The only thing I could parse from the logs is that my /etc/hosts configuration might be broken. I fixed that issue and it still does not work.

Comment: The Samba logs will tell you what the server thinks is going on when someone tries to connect by IP address.